# How I can get one line output for two for loop in python?

Tags: python

```
a=7
for a1 in range(0,a):
    print('-',end ='')
print("Welcome"),
for a2 in range(0,a):
    print('-',end ='')
```

Output is coming as :

```
-------Welcome
-------
```

But I want the output as:

```
-------Welcome-------
```

Comment: You already seem to know how to use `end` in `print()`, you are clearly very close. Did you copy code from somewhere and not know what it does?

Answer (score 0):

The `print()` function is defaulted to have a newline character (`\n`) at the end of every print. Between the two for loops, you `print("Welcome")` and have forgotten to change what is added to the end of the print statement. You change the ending character with the keyword argument, so `end=''` means there will be nothing added to the end.
Hopefully this explains the problem if and if you don't know what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=7
for a1 in range(0,a):
    print('-',end ='')
print("Welcome",end ='')
for a2 in range(0,a):
    print('-',end ='',flush=True)
```